# Export large data to CSV using PHP

Tags: php, sql, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to export some data to CSV using PHP.

My code:

```
function download_send_headers($filename) {
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}

$givenTerm = $_POST['TextBoxList'];

$sql_query = "select * from some_table where key=".$givenTerm;
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql_query);
$r1 = array();
$file = fopen("php://output", 'w');
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)){
    $valuesArray=array();
    foreach($row as $name => $value)
    {
        $valuesArray[]=$value;
    }
    fputcsv($file,$valuesArray);
}
fclose($file);
download_send_headers("data_export_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");

die();
```

Here I am receiving a search-value from a form in another page and then triggering a query based on it. The code is working fine for smaller data-sets(up to 100). But when the number of rows is more in the result (around 600-700) then the code crashes. Please tell me how to fix this.

P.S. I am using Sql Server 2012 for the database.

Comment: You probably have to increase `max_execution_time` and `memory_limit` in your php settings.

Comment: Don't build a big array of data that uses lots of memory, then convert that entire array to csv (also in memory); loop through your records converting each one directly to csv, then outputting directly.... faster and uses a lot less memory

Comment: If you're using SQL server, why don't you export the CSV's from there?

Comment: @MarkBaker I had also used that approach. But the result was the same.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Because I have to take some input from the user, and based on the input I run the query.

Comment: @TobiasKun I don't want to change my entire PHP settings for execution of 1 file. Can we change that for a particular individual file ?

Comment: What errors are you getting in the php error logs/webserver logs?

Comment: @shanal - you can increase memory for a particular script using ini_set() - depending on your hosting: many ISPs disable this though

Answer (score 1):

Instead of first getting all results in a single array and then outputting it, you could also fetch it row by row and outputting each row directly. 
That way you won't need the massive amount of memory to fit the entire array in.

Comment: I have modified my code according to your suggestion. But the problem is persisting.